# jquery имитация клика

Tags: jquery

есть код `$('.method_delivery div.method_item:eq(3)').show();`
который показывает поле с радио кнопкой
как имитировать нажатии на нее?

```
 var sum = parseInt($('.b_b_price').text().replace(' ', '').replace(',', '.'));
    if (sum < 1000) {

        $(".basket_b_oform ").html("<p style='color: red ;background: white; height: 100%;text-align:              center;'>Оформление доступно при сумме заказа свыше 1000 руб</p>");
        $('.method_delivery div.method_item:eq(3)').hide();
        $('.method_delivery div.method_item:eq(2)').show().click();;

    }else if(sum >= 1000 && sum <= 10000) {
        $('.basket_buy.cb').prepend("<div class='test'style='color: red ;background: white; height: 100%;text-align: center; padding-bottom: 10px;'> При заказе до 1000 руб. к сумме заказа прибавляется 500 руб. за доставку до транспортной компании </div>");
        $('.method_delivery div.method_item:eq(2)').hide();
        $('.method_delivery div.method_item:eq(3)').show().click();;

    }else {

        $('.method_delivery div.method_item:eq(3)').hide();
        $('.method_delivery div.method_item:eq(2)').show().click();;


    }
});
```

Comment: $(селектор).trigger('click') смотрели?

Comment: Вы бы лучше предоставили полный обаботчик, в котором находится .show()

Comment: какой смысл Вы вкладываете в `.replace(',', '.')` внутри `parseInt`?

Comment: что не работает в приведенном коде?

Comment: не срабатывает клик

Comment: @gbrgbr Как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: @gbrgbr правильно ли я понимаю, что внутри скрываемых/отображаемых дивов у вас лежат радиокнопки и вам нужно имитировать клик именно на них?

Comment: Да правильно понимаете

Comment: <div class="method_items">
 <div class="method_item">
 <label>
 <div class="mi_radio_left">
 <span class="radio ">
 <input type="radio" name="f_delivery" value="">
 </span>
 </div>
 </div>    
 вот такая вложенность

Comment: @gbrgbr все эти детали нужно изначально указывать в вопросе, а не ждать, пока из вас их вытянут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кликать надо инпутом, а не дивом. Предполагая, что радиокнопка внутри `div.method_item` одна:

```
$('.method_delivery div.method_item:eq(2)').show().find("input[type='radio']").click();
```

Comment: Спасибо , очень благодарен

Answer (score 2):

Логично, что будет как-то так:

```
$('.method_delivery div.method_item:eq(3)').click();
```

Если сразу после появления, то можно по цепочке:

```
$('.method_delivery div.method_item:eq(3)').show().click();
```

Comment: не работает этот способ .trigger('click') тоже

Comment: @gbrgbr какие ошибки при этом? для понимания потребуется минимально воспроизводимый пример вашего кода

Comment: .show() куда девать?

Comment: @gbrgbr если Вам нужен клик после появления некого элемента, то у метода show есть колбэк функция для реализации данного поведения, либо покажите код

Comment: да нужен клик после появления вот этого элемента $('.method_delivery div.method_item:eq(3)').show()

Comment: @gbrgbr все прекрасно работает. если это тот самый инпут. show никуда девать не надо

Comment: @gbrgbr ну например можно написать `$('.method_delivery div.method_item:eq(3)').show().click();`

Comment: выложил код посмотрите пожалуйста , так не работает....

Comment: @gbrgbr а html где? что именно не работает? ошибки пишет в консоли или даже ошибки не пишет?

Comment: ошибки нет , просто не работает клик по ним